# How can I set a button to change the background color of a button

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to make it so I can press a-d, and the buttons(a, b, c, d) will change color; When I press 'a', the a button is supposed to turn a darker color, if I press 'b', for example, 'a' is supposed to change back to it's original color. And 'b' will become a darker color,
This probably is not the most efficient, but it's one of the most efficient ways I could think of.

My code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 65)
    {
        document.getElementById("a1").style.background='#BFBFBF';
        document.getElementById("b1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("c1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 66)
    {
        document.getElementById("b1").style.background='#BFBFBF';
        document.getElementById("c1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("a1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
    }
    else if(event.keycode == 67)
    {
        document.getElementById("c1").style.background='#BFBFBF';
        document.getElementById("d1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("a1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("b1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
    }
    else if(event.keycode == 68)
    {
        document.getElementById("d1").style.background='#BFBFBF';
        document.getElementById("a1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("b1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
        document.getElementById("c1").style.background='#FFFFFF';
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 65)
    {
        event01()
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 66)
    {
        event02()
    }
    else if(event.keycode == 67)
    {
        event03()
    }
    else if(event.keycode == 68)
    {
        event04()
    }
});
```

Comment: Let me know if you want to see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
~function () {
  var opts = {
    65: { button: "a1", handler: eventA },
    66: { button: "b1", handler: eventB },
    67: { button: "c1", handler: eventC },
    68: { button: "d1", handler: eventD }
  };

 
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    var cur = opts[event.keyCode];
    cur && (document.getElementById(cur.button).style.background='#BFBFBF');
  });

  document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    var cur = opts[event.keyCode];
    if (cur) {
      document.getElementById(cur.button).style.background = '';
      cur.handler();
    }
  });

  function eventA() {}
  function eventB() {}
  function eventC() {}
  function eventD() {}
}();
```

```css
button {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<button id=a1>a</button>
<button id=b1>b</button>
<button id=c1>c</button>
<button id=d1>d</button>
```